# Installing HPL, makefile problems

Tags: benchmarking, makefile

I've followed [this guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-hpl-application-note/) up until step 5. When I run `$make arch=intel64` it gives me the following output:

```
make -f Make.top startup_dir     arch=intel64
make[1]: Entering directory `/hpl-2.0'
Make.intel64:106: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/hpl-2.0'
make: *** [startup] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what it means by "missing separator".

Edit: I have the following in the makefile at lines 103-106:

```
LAdir         = /opt/intel/mk/lib/intel64
LAinc         = /opt/intel/mkl/include
LAlib         = -Wl,--start-
group $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_thread.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_core.a -Wl, --end-group -lpthread -lm
```

This is exactly what the guide says to put, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the guide's formatting is a bit misleading and suspect that these lines in the makefile:

```
LAlib         = -Wl,--start-
group $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_thread.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_core.a -Wl, --end-group -lpthread -lm
```

Should actually be a single line as follows:

```
LAlib         = -Wl,--start-group $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_lp64.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_intel_thread.a $(LAdir)/libmkl_core.a -Wl, --end-group -lpthread -lm
```

In other words, if you have a line break after the --start- on line 105 then remove that and make sure line 106 that currently starts with `group` is moved to the end of line 105.

Comment: That took care of that error. I ran it, and it did a lot of stuff, but it has a different error and it stopped. I'm making a new question. Thanks so much, and sorry for not responding quickly.

Comment: No probs, glad it could help!