# Makefile fails to install file correctly, installing HPL

Tags: linux, benchmarking, makefile, hpc

I started installing HPL a while ago and had a related [question](https://superuser.com/questions/266988/installing-hpl-makefile-problems). I've been following along with [this guide from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-tools-for-software-developers-hpl-application-note/). I figure this warrants a whole new one. When I try to make the archive, the output seems fine until the end, where it gives an error.

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/hpl-2.0/src/auxil/intel64'
Makefile:47: Make.inc: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `Make.inc'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/hpl-2.0/src/auxil/intel64'
make[1]: *** [build_src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/hpl-2.0'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Going to the directory `/hpl-2.0/src/auxil/intel64` shows a file, "Make.inc", but it's highlighted red, and the white text blinks.

Is there a way to manually make that file? What do I need to do to get the makefile to do this for me?

Comment: Found out that Make.inc is linked to another file, but it isn't the right file. How do I change the link?

Answer (score 3):

in `Make.top` there's a line where it's trying to create a symlink:

```
   $(LN_S) $(TOPdir)/Make.$(arch) Make.inc
```

the command fails if the source code directory is not `$(HOME)/hpl`, `TOPdir` variable should be defined in your `Make.intel64`:

```
TOPdir       = $(HOME)/hpl
```

Changing the variable to your actual path should solve the problem (or move source code to `$(HOME)/hpl`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the new name hpl-2.0 used in the tar, I solved with:

```
# mv hpl-2.0 hpl
```